# Is there a convenient way to check which worksheets have changed when comparing excel files with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: javascript, excel, svn, tortoisesvn, office-js

Show changes of a commit in **svn log**:

[image]

As you can see, the cells with changes are indeed marked red -- **but THAT'S ALL**.
[image]

There are **2 problems**:

1. if the workbook has multiple worksheets, you have to traverse all worksheets because you don't know exactly which worksheets have been changed.
2. if a worksheet has many rows (or many columns), you need to drag a long scroll bar to look for cells with changes.

---

**What I have tried**:

1. I did some google, many people say to use SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.exe, but I found that the latest version of Office has removed this feature.
2. I tried to modify the script that svn uses to handle excel compare:

   mouse right click menu > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Diff Viewer > Advanced

   .xlsx => wscript.exe "D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts\diff-xls.js" %base %mine //E:javascript

```
var used_range_base = objBaseWorksheet.UsedRange;

var used_range_new = objNewWorksheet.UsedRange;
var n_row_new = used_range_new.Rows.Count;
var n_col_new = used_range_new.Columns.Count;

var any_cell_diff = false;
                
for (var row = 1; row <= n_row_new; row++) {
  for (var col = 1; col <= n_col_new; col++) {
    if (used_range_new.Cells(row, col).value2 !== used_range_base.Cells(row, col).value2) {
      objNewWorksheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 7; // if any cell changed, mark the sheet's tab
      any_cell_diff = true;
      break;
    }
  }
    
  if (any_cell_diff) {
    break;
  }
}
```

This will indeed mark the modified worksheets:
[image]

BUT -- I don't know why, this algorithm is **extremly slow**...

---

So, **finally my question is**:

1. Is there any efficient way to check if 2 worksheets have any difference?
2. Is there a way to mark all the changed cells in a sheet ?(like marking the color line on the scroll bar)
   [image]

Comment: Indeed, [Spreadsheet Compare](https://support.microsoft.com/office/overview-of-spreadsheet-compare-13fafa61-62aa-451b-8674-242ce5f2c986) is only available with Office Professional Plus 2013, Office Professional Plus 2016, Office Professional Plus 2019, or Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise **however** Microsoft 365 has the [Spreadsheet Inquire add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/office/turn-on-the-inquire-add-in-6bc668e2-f3c6-4729-8ce1-75ea20aa9d90) available. **See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/office/compare-workbooks-using-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42)**.

Comment: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/inquire.htm
"Inquire
Added in 2013 and removed in 2016
Also known as Spreadsheet Compare, Spreadsheet Inquire or Spreadsheet Management.
Was only available in Office 2013 Professional Plus and cannot be downloaded from the Microsoft website.
This add-in is no longer available for download from Microsoft."